# In MySql, how to create a sequential set of values based on a record id where a specific related_id is available

Tags: mysql

What I am attempting to do is populate a value of 1, 2, 3, 4 based on the sequence of the primary key id, from low to high, where a repetitive value is present. Also, only doing this update based on a class value of 'jt'.

Example:

```
ID   abstract_id   class   jump_no
101   123           st        null
102   123           st        null
103   123           jt        1
104   123           jt        2
105   205           jt        1
106   205           jt        2
107   205           jt        3
108   391           st        null
```

Currently my table has all null value for the jump_no column. I am trying to populate that sequence, per abstract_id grouping but only with a class value of 'jt'.
So the 1, 2, 3, 4 "counter" restarts for every new abstract_id.

Comment: If an answer has solved the issue, consider marking it as 'accepted'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.  One uses correlated subqueries.  Another that I use more often uses `user-defined variables`:

```
update yourtable y 
join ( 
    select id, abstract_id, 
       case abstract_id 
                when @prev_abstract_id 
                then @jump_no := @jump_no + 1 
                else @jump_no := 1 AND @prev_abstract_id := abstract_id end jump_no
    from yourtable join (select @jump_no:=0, @prev_abstract_id:=0) t
    order by id, abstract_id) t on y.id = t.id
set y.jump_no = t.jump_no;
```

- [Online SQL Example](http://rextester.com/NHO35263)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for that answer. A great solution. I was quite far off from that.
Thanks again, and thanks for throwing the online SQL example up there

Comment: Sorry, I missed one thing. there is a class column as well.
3 class values (jt, st, at), I only want to do this update on the jt class records.
Would that just be a where clause at the end?

where y.class = 'at' ?

Comment: Well i made that edit to the query in SQL Example and that did not do that trick...

Comment: Edits to the original question have been made to include the 'class' value

Comment: I figured out where I needed to place my where clause.
Thanks again for the fast help!

clause placed before the 'order by'.